# sqlite syntax error with case expression

Tags: sqlite, syntax-error, case

I wrote a query as

> SELECT
>    case when "Whether you like it or not" = 1
>    then 'I like it'
>    from myrestaurants;"

the sqlite said 
Error: near "from": syntax error
I have tried different combinations with the case statement, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `"Whether you like it or not"` is a column holding an integer then all your query is missing is an `end` in the `case` expression:

```
select case when "Whether you like it or not" = 1 then 'I like it' end 
from myrestaurants
```